# how to transfer geometry from one column to an empty column on postgre sql

Tags: mysql, postgresql, postgis

i used alter table to create a new column(named geom, 2157) but transferring geo informations from **geom 4386 column** to new geom, 2157 column is a problem

```
ALTER TABLE major ADD COLUMN gem geometry(POINT, 2157);
UPDATE major SET geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint, 2157);
```

Answer (score 1):

[`ST_Transform`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Transform.html) is what you're looking for:

Sample Data

```
CREATE TABLE t (geom GEOMETRY(POINT,4326));
INSERT INTO t VALUES ('SRID=4326;POINT(-4.43 54.32)'::GEOMETRY);
ALTER TABLE t ADD COLUMN geom2 geometry(POINT,2157);
```

To update the new geometry column with the geometry transformed to the SRS `2157` just use `ST_Transform` as follows:

```
UPDATE t SET geom2 = ST_Transform(geom,2157);
```

And here is your transformed geometry:

```
 SELECT ST_AsText(geom), ST_AsText(geom2) FROM t;
     st_astext      |                st_astext                 
--------------------+------------------------------------------
 POINT(-4.43 54.32) | POINT(832216.581140537 847131.995720883)
(1 Zeile)
```